# angularjs order of script files

Tags: angularjs

If you recieve an error like this one:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'some module' is not available! You either misspelled the
module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies  
as the second argument.
```

it may be due to the order of files in your index.html. The modules definition

```
angular.module('moduleName', [])
```

should be included before any of its modules

```
angular.module ('moduleName').something
```

this result an error, but files will still work. 
I am posting it for the help of others that may get it. 
This may occur if you do not specify the files manually in your index, but leave it to an automation tool (e.g. grunt) to create it for you during build phase. E.g. like the one done in https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp (which is great, by all other means!)